# What is the best way to export application logs from Azure app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Our web app is hosted on Azure App Service. It generates application logs stored locally at /site/wwwroot/Log/. The logs are size limited so we have log.txt (latest), log0.txt..log20.txt (0 is oldest).

I'd like to make the logs available to other members of the team without giving them ftp write access to the web application.

I explored providing ftp read access but that is not possible with Azure.

I am open to very simple solutions I can implement in a few hours as well as holistic solutions (log analysis solution, etc..). Budget is a concern.

We use staging slots as well so that may complicate matters but it's a secondary concern right now.

How can I best do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to make the logs available to other members of the team without giving them ftp write access to the web application.

Azure Web App provides 2 ways to store the application logs. File System and Blob Storage. You could turn on the Blob Storage to save the application logs to Azure Blob Storage. After that, we can create a shared access signatures (SAS) which could grant read-only access for Blob Storage.

If you don't want to turn on Application Log Blob Storage, you could read the logs from your File System and share them to your team members. The log files are stored in "D:\home\LogFiles". We can read them out using File and Directory classes provided by .NET Framework. I created a ASP.NET MVC sample code to do it. Code below is for your reference.

**Models which will be used to pass folder and file information to view.**

```
public class LogFolder
{
    public LogFolder() { }

    public LogFolder(string virtualPath)
    {
        FolderVirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public string FolderName
    {
        get
        {
            int lastIndex = FolderVirtualPath.LastIndexOf(@"\");
            if (lastIndex < 0 && FolderVirtualPath.Length > 0) { return FolderVirtualPath; }
            else { return FolderVirtualPath.Substring(lastIndex + 1); }
        }
    }

    public string FolderVirtualPath { get; set; }

    public string FolderPath {
        get
        {
            return Path.Combine(@"D:\home\LogFiles\", FolderVirtualPath);
        }
    }

    public List<LogFolder> SubFolders { get; set; }

    public List<LogFile> SubFiles { get; set; }

    public void GetSubFilesAndFolders()
    {
        SubFolders = new List<LogFolder>();
        IEnumerable<string> folders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(FolderPath);
        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            SubFolders.Add(new LogFolder(folder.Replace(@"D:\home\LogFiles", "")));
        }
        SubFiles = new List<LogFile>();
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(FolderPath);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            SubFiles.Add(new LogFile(file.Replace(@"D:\home\LogFiles", "")));
        }
    }
}

public class LogFile
{
    public LogFile() { }

    public LogFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        FileVirtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    //Used to display the file name
    public string FileName { get { return Path.GetFileName(FilePath); } }

    public string FileVirtualPath { get; set; }

    //used to download the file
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return Path.Combine(@"D:\home\LogFiles\", FileVirtualPath); }
    }
}
```

**Controllers which are used to show folder information and download file from server side.**

```
public ActionResult Folder(string folderVirtualPath)
{
    LogFolder folder = new LogFolder(folderVirtualPath);
    folder.GetSubFilesAndFolders();
    return View(folder);
}

public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileVirtualPath)
{
    LogFile file = new LogFile(fileVirtualPath);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(file.FilePath))
    {
        return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file.FilePath), "application/octet-stream", file.FilePath);
    }
    else
    {
        return HttpNotFound("File Not Found");
    }   
}
```

**View which is used to show the folder information.**

```
@model TestAccessFIles.Controllers.LogFolder
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Folder";
}

<h2>Folder : @Model.FolderVirtualPath </h2>

<h3>Sub Folders</h3>
<ul>
@foreach (var folder in Model.SubFolders)
{
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Folder",new { folderVirtualPath = folder.FolderVirtualPath })">@folder.FolderName</a></li>
}
</ul>

<h3>Sub Files</h3>
<ul>
    @foreach (var file in Model.SubFiles)
    {
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile",new { fileVirtualPath = file.FileVirtualPath })">@file.FileName</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```